# How do I change the value of a field with an initialized value?

Tags: java

This is the code with the main Class

I don't know how to update the stock. I tried encapsulation.

```
System.out.println("Cellphone Choice:\niPhone 10: $500\tSamsung: $450\tOppo: $300\n");
System.out.println("Input Name: ");
name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Input Supplier: ");
supp = scan.nextLine();
try {
    do {
        System.out.println("Input Quantity: "+cp.getStock()+" STOCK"); //cp.getStock is initialized=80
        quan = scan.nextInt();
    }while(quan > cp.getStock());
    System.out.println("Input Price of Selected Cellphone: ");
    scan.nextLine();
    price = scan.nextDouble();
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Please Input Number!");
}
cp = new Cellphone(name,supp,quan,price);
```

This code is from my other class

```
int stockCp = 80;
public void getProductionInfo() {
    System.out.println("Buyer Name: "+name);
    System.out.println("Supplier: "+supplier);
    int qSold = stockCp - quantity;
    System.out.println("Quantity left: "+qSold);
}
```

So the `qSold` is now the new Value of the total stock left.

example in the quantity is 10 so I got only 70 stocks left.

I did a `do..while` loop so that you can select cellphone choice again.

How to update the `getStock` to 70 since I took 10 quantity of stock before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to simply change the line

```
int qSold = stockCp - quantity;
```

to

```
stockCp = stockCp - quantity;
```

if I understand your problem correct.